# How to change the cellsize, xllcorner and yllcorner of an ASCII file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

I need to convert the `cellsize`, `xllcorner` and `yllcorner` of multiple ASCII files from `m` into `km`.
I've been trying to overwrite them in the header of the ASCII files like I would with a regular text file, like this:

```
for rw_file in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Marie\Test"):
    rw_file_path = os.path.join(r"C:\Users\Marie\Test", rw_file)
    with open(rw_file_path, 'r+') as f:
        # skip the first two lines of the header
        f.readline()
        f.readline()
        # convert the values of cellsize, xllcorner and yllcorner into km
        line3 = f.readline()
        header_x, xllcorner = line3.split()
        xllcorner_new = int(xllcorner) / 1000
        f.seek(2)
        f.write(re.sub(header_x, xllcorner_new)) #third argument??
        line4 = f.readline()
        header_y, yllcorner = line4.split()
        yllcorner_new = int(yllcorner) / 1000
        f.seek(3)
        f.write(re.sub(header_y, yllcorner_new))
        line5 = f.readline()
        header_size, cellsize = line5.split()
        cellsize_new = int(cellsize) / 1000
        f.seek(4)
        f.write(re.sub(header_size, cellsize_new))
```

But of course the function re.sub needs three arguments. I am not sure how else to do this. I'm still a beginner so I'm sure there is an easy way, but I can't find it.
Can I overwrite these lines in the header somehow, or is there another way?

Comment: This is really quite unclear. Try to reduce the code and your problem statement to a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write into a new file (and then maybe copy that new file over the old one) instead of changing the old file in-place. Since the new values you're writing into the file are of a different size in bytes than the old ones, changing it in-place will produce garbage content.

As for your specfic question about `re.sub`, you can find its documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub. It requires the string to be changed as its 3rd parameter.

Comment: Thank you! Writing it into a new file is definitely a better idea :)